# Detecting Installation Source with react-native-fbsdk

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm facing a problem with `react-native-fbsdk`. I'd like to know whether the user has installed the app by coming through Facebook Ads or has he/she installed it organically from store (App Store, Play Store). **Is this even possible with React Native?**

The reason is, I need to log events for analytics restricted only on installations done via Facebook. There are pre-defined events, like *App Installs* and *App Launches* tracked, but my events are custom events.

I have assumption that either `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` or `AppEventsLogger.getUserID()` would return something when the installation is performed through FB. On dev environment, both returns `null` which is kind of expected. However these ideas could only be tested on production and this isn't an option.

So the actual question is: *"How do I detect whether the user is coming through Facebook advertisement link?"*

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Thanks

Comment: @Bataleon technically, no. But we found a way to filter people inside dashboard / console between installed and non-installed users via FB.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply.

Comment: any update on this? Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ManjunathGk unfortunately not programmatically . However, the info should be visible in the analytics console. But this was 2.5 years ago